# Problems using Mesa demos

Tags: linux, graphics, centos, opengl

I successfully installed Mesa with "yum install Mesa*" and downloaded MesaDemos-7.8.tar.gz   archive.
Now I try follow instructions from "Mesa3d.org -> Download / Insall -> Compiling and   Installing -> 1.5 Running the demos",
but in progs/demos there is only *.c files, when I try to compile them,
I get many similar errors like:

```
gears.c:(.text+0x54): undefined reference to `glShadeModel'
```

I guess that this is very noob question, and I understand that there is very simple   solution, but I haven't any idea...
In beggining of the file there are all necessary #includes:

```
#include <math.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>  
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <string.h>  
#include <GL/glut.h>
```

So I have some questions:
Is there some Mesa forum on the web?
Is there some compiled demos?
Is there some site with well described examples of Mesa using?
What I need for compile those examples?

I have CentOS 5

Thank you for ahead.

Comment: So I guess, may be I should use:
cc -o gears gears.c -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lMesatk -lMesaGL -lXext -lX11 -lm, but than I get:
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lMesatk

Comment: In demo directory lays Makefile, but when I doing: makem I get error: Makefile:4: ../../configs/current: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `../../configs/current'.  Stop. 
Some one know what I must to do?

Comment: this is sort of programming related, but I don't feel strongly enough about it to migrate it to Stack Overflow. Thank you for following up and answering your own question, rodnower, so others can benefit from this solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, this is necessary to do ./configure before all in root Mesa unarchived directory, like described here:
http://www.mesa3d.org/install.html#unix-x11